# Как заполнить series ближайшим неотрицательным значением в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть pandas series примерно такой:

```
|column|
|----|
|-999|
|-999|
|0.1|
|0.15|
|-999|
|0.3|
|0.7|
|-999|
```

То есть в нем упорядоченные значения по возрастанию и есть пропущенные значения в виде -999, которые нужно заменить на ближайшее неотрицательное значение, при чем пока без разницы будет это большее или меньшее. В моем примере на выходе должно быть примерно как в колонке new_column:

```
|column|new_column|
|----|------|
|-999|0.1|
|-999|0.1|
|0.1|0.1|
|0.15|0.15|
|-999|0.3|
|0.3|0.3|
|0.7|0.7|
|-999|0.7|
```

Логически понимаю, что надо как то через рекурсию или через while пробегаться по массиву всех чисел, пока не найдем отличное от -999, но как быть в ситуациях где в одном случае большее число нужно брать, а в другом меньшее. В общем по кускам вроде понимаю, а как объединить в рабочее решение не пойму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `Pandas` есть все нужные функции для этого. Обычно не бывает таких случаев, когда нужно что-то делать в цикле, всё можно сделать в "векторной форме" (сразу со всем вектором данных):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(map(float, "-999|-999|0.1|0.15|-999|0.3|0.7|-999".split('|')))
print(s)
s[s == -999] = pd.NA
s = s.bfill().ffill()
print(s)
```

Вывод:

```
0   -999.00
1   -999.00
2      0.10
3      0.15
4   -999.00
5      0.30
6      0.70
7   -999.00
dtype: float64

0    0.10
1    0.10
2    0.10
3    0.15
4    0.30
5    0.30
6    0.70
7    0.70
dtype: float64
```

Comment: !! Что-то я про эту пару ф-ций подзабыл.  Красиво.

Comment: Задача может быть не такой тривиальной если заполнять нужно действительно ближайшим неотрицательным. Кстати, а где в решении вы учли «неотрицательность» элементов? ;)

Comment: @MaxU -  думаю, ТС будет счастлив ответу (хотя пока никак не отреагировал),  т.к. в такие тонкости вряд-ли вдавался, когда вопрос формулировал. Но Вы подметили правильно. Наверное надо новый вопрос открывать, для поиска абсолютно корректного варианта решения.

Comment: @MaxU Да, я несколько поверхностно подошёл, но из имеющихся примеров напрашивалось такое решение )

Comment: @passant На соревнованиях по time series что-то такое регулярно приходится делать, особенно для всяких вычисляемых фич типа скользящего среднего, чтобы у регрессии крыша не сильно ехала на пропусках в данных )

Comment: @CrazyElf  Вот это да, спасибо большое!! И вы правильно подметили, что задача то у меня на самом деле сложней, но на данном этапе мне достаточно заполнять именно ближайшими значениями, так что решение то что нужно,  спасибо еще раз!